# ECS, which of daemon or replica are more used for web services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

When creating ECS services, we can choose daemon(one task per one instance) or replica (specify number of tasks)

For scaling web front (nginx, uwsgi for python web stack), I initially thought daemon because that's how one would scale ec2 without ecs.

But then, I read people rather scale tasks (I think it implies replica) and I'm confused.

It's weird that you have to scale task and container (ec2) . 
What's the advantage of scaling task/container separately?

Answer (score 0):

Daemon only run one task in an ECS container instance and if you want to run more than one task in your container instance you will have to use Replica. Using replica you can use auto-scaling features for tasks. So if you want to run more than one task on your container instance you can do it via Replica provided you have enough CPU/Memory available. Once your CPU/Memory threshold is breached you can configure the auto-scaling feature for your container instance which will increase the number of container instance in your cluster.

So auto-scaling of task is related to replica and auto-scaling of container instance is based on non-availability of the resources for processing.